# Save lines to different files based on the date

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

How can I force a re-evaluation of this each time?

```
cat > $(date '+%H-%M-%S').log
```

So that when I first output something it gets written to one file, and after a few seconds I make another ouput and it will be saved in a new file.

`cat` just symbolizes a always running program

Comment: Code in `$(...)` **is** evaluated each time.

Comment: Doesn't work anyway

Comment: Maybe you called it in the same second? Try adding `-%N` at the end.

Comment: I'm waiting several seconds. And %N made no difference

Comment: Do you call exactly the same code as shown?

Comment: Yes, once. `cat` symbolizes a always running instance of any program. Which is not restarted.

Comment: Oh, wait, I understand the question now.

Comment: You want to change the output file for a running instance of `cat` - per se?

Comment: Yes :) One instance which is always running that changes the output file for example at midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced `cat` with a for loop that emits one line per second:

```
for ch in {a..e} ; do echo $ch ; sleep 1 ; done | \
while IFS= read -r line ; do printf '%s\n' "$line" >> $(date +%H-%M-%S) ; done
```

I used `>>` instead of `>` if more than one line comes in one second. You might need to add the month + day to not mix output from different days.

Comment: So can't be done with just bash? and where did my `cat` go? :)

Comment: I replaced `cat` with the `for` loop.

Comment: @Markus: OK, removed Perl.

Comment: Can you explain the edit? IFS= ? -r flag on read? printf instead of echo? thanks!

Comment: @Markus: Ask Gilles, he added those :-) Or read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/13792